# Navicat query - from utf8 to varbinary

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Good day,

I'm having some troubles with inserting data into my MySQL table using Navicat.
I have set everywhere UTF-8, but still some strings are inserted incorrectly.

One example:
**Legendární dračí onyx**
Got inserted as:
**LegendĂˇrnĂ­ draÄŤĂ­ onyx**

Places, where I have UTF-8 set:

- Connection properties -> Encoding -> UTF-8
- Database properties -> Character set -> utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode
- Database properties -> Collation -> utf8_general_ci
- Design Table -> Options -> Character set -> utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode
- Design Table -> Options -> Collation -> utf8_general_ci
- File with query has encoding UTF-8 (set in PS-PAD) without BOM

Problem is:
Fields with those wrongly inserted strings are type **varbinary** (I cannot change that).

How can I insert those UTF8 strings, so they will be inserted correctly AS IS ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try doing this before inserting the data `SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';`

Comment: Hi Mike, I have done this - it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I have used latin2 Czech and now everything works.
Navicat seems to have problem with these symbols in UTF-8.